# Active Directory Domain Service started then stopped after dcpromo

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, domain-controller

I use Windows Server 2008 to install Active Directory follow [**this guide**](http://www.howtogeek.com/99323/installing-active-directory-on-server-2008-r2/) After a restart, I can only login to local account,not domain account due to the error `No logon server are available!`

I check the services and find out that ADDS service is stopped, so I start it but it immediately stops and report:

```
This sevice on local computer started and then stopped. some serivces stop automatically if then are not in use by other serives or programs
```

So how to fix this? And a 2nd question: after run `dcpromo`, what is the default domain administrator account?

Any ideas are appreciated :)

Comment: `1.` Did you install DNS when you ran DCPROMO? `2.` The password for the domain Administrator account will be the same as the password for the local Administrator account was before your ran DCPROMO.

Comment: Yes, I installed it, according to the guide I mentioned above. Are there anything wrong :(

Comment: What do you have set for DNS server(s) in the TCP/IPv4 properties of the network card on the domain controller?

Comment: Seems the setup did it automatically, I see it change to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: It's weird, `nslookup testServer.com` return `DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
Server:  UnKnown
Address:  ::1` . Meanwhile, `nslookup testServer.com 127.0.0.1` return `127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thank you for your attention, I was able to fix it by reinstall windows, maybe there's a problem with the setup :)

Answer (score -1):

Does the server have more than one network adapter?  If it does, disable all but one.  On that one active adapter make sure it has a static IPv4 address assigned with the DNS set to 127.0.0.1.  In the IPv6 settings of the network adapter remove ::1 from the list of DNS servers.  Finally from a elevated command prompt run "ipconfig /registerdns".

Comment: The OP already mentioned they reinstalled Windows.  But they also mentioned that the DNS settings were already set to 127.0.0.1.